Is this what a bad blower motor sounds like on a 2014 Ford Escape?
I have a 2014 Escape and the blower sounds like the video below.
https://photos.app.goo.gl/MCN2MmGPNyair5Rb9
If you don't watch the video, it sounds a little like a 2-stroke motor in the dash and the clunking speed goes along with the AC fan speed.
Is this a bad one? I have had intermittent issues in the past where air would just stop blowing out the vents for awhile, then it would come back and be fine (with the fan on the same speed).
I think I need a blower, but have not heard this before...

It's clearly related to the blower but to me it doesn't sound like a bad motor; it sounds like an unbalanced blower wheel.
Bad motors that I've heard sound more screechy and whiny.
You may have a cracked blower wheel or a missing turbine blade. You could even have a mummified mouse stuck in the blower wheel, throwing the whole thing off balance.
So I suggest you not order a replacement blower motor, but set aside some time to take out the blower motor and its attached blower wheel and see what's up.

The correct answer belongs to @MTA
I found a dead mouse (I had a small bore scope I use with my phone), and here's how I found fixed it:

Remove cabin air filter
Attach bore scope to phone
Stick it in air filter hole and into the fan
See half a mouse
Shove shop vac in air filter hole and pull out half a mouse
Take off windshield wipers and windshield shroud/cowl pieces
Stick shop vac behind windshield and remove second half of mouse
Put cowl and wipers back together
Close up car and run AC on high
Spray in a shitload of ozone odor remover in and shut doors for 15 minutes
Turn off car
Install new cabin air filter

That's it, heck of a lot better than removing half the dash on both sides to pull the fan out.
Here's the first half of the mouse:

Pretty sure one of these idiots ate the other half:


Kudos for reporting on the resolution to the problem, which is sadly rare on this Stack, and I hope to see more high quality contributions from you here in the future. Nice job!
